# Get percentage of records with certain category

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with column `category`. These columns are of STRING type.

How can I get the percentage of total records with that category?

So far I have:

`select category, count(1) from table group by category;`

Expected output:

```
category | count | percent
cat_a       10       10
cat_b       80       80
cat_c       10       10
```

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, not a dupliate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
category, COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()::REAL
FROM table t
GROUP BY 1
```

In PostgreSQL, you can use window functions and aggregate functions together.

The windows are evaluated after *join*, *where*, *group by*, and having clauses, and there can be multiple windows.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Just put your query into an outer query using window functions:

```
SELECT category, cnt,
       cnt / sum(cnt) OVER () AS percent
FROM (SELECT category, count(1) AS cnt
      FROM "table"
      GROUP BY category) q;
```